# How to remove all html tags and it's inner html + content and gets only the text outside all html tags

Tags: php, html, regex

```
$content = 'text <div>sample text<div>sample<div>sample</div>sample</div><div>sample</div></div><figure><p>sample</figure>';
```

I wanted to get the output as 'text'

Tried many regex found in StackOverflow, but nothing really do my purpose exactly.

Comment: use `DOMDocument` rather than a Regex

Comment: Do you have more examples?

Comment: @klediooo used almost all the regex found in stackoverflow

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I am trying without using DOMDocument, Is any way to do it without DOMDocument

Comment: I mean more examples, which content should pass the Regex and which not.